# Always point to same url jquery background

Tags: jquery, url

How can I make to always get same url, so the image path won't change. It's ok if domain is www.domain.com/cat but then www.domain.com/cat/cat it points to cat/images/img.jpg

```
"background-image" : "url(../images/" + photoObject.image + ")",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "../" it means "look in the parent directory of this document".

If you start with "/", it means  "start looking from the root directory"

So for example,

```
"background-image" : "url(/images/" + photoObject.image + ")",
```

If the root of the site is /cat then use

```
"background-image" : "url(/cat/images/" + photoObject.image + ")",
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a global variable in your js and assign the site root with the root domain.

Example for MVC in the main layout of the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">siteRoot = '@Url.Content("~/")';</script>
```

then you can use it like this:

```
"background-image" : "url("+siteRoot + "images/" + photoObject.image + ")"
```

and your image can stay in the same location and it will always point there